# C++ enum EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, enums

I have a problem with the enumerations in c++
I don't understand why if I define two variables with the same enumeration it give EXC_BAD_ACCESS 
do you have an idea why? if I define only one varible it is fine
here is the code...

```
enum directions{
    UP,
    DOWN,
    RIGHT,
    LEFT,
    IN,
    OUT,
    FW,
    RW
};

class Snake
{
private:
    enum directions head_dir;
    enum directions head_dir_ask; //if I comment this... the program work fine..
    (... other stuff...)
};
```

thanks for the help in advance
the code is about 10 files... it will be like too long to post,
anyway...
I'm using OpenGL and Qt

```
MainProject::MainProject(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainProject)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    startTimer(1000);
    glwidget = new MyGLBox(ui->centralWidget);
    ui->GLlayout->addWidget(glwidget); // <line where the complier retruns the EXC_BAD_ACCESS
}
```

MyGLBox constructor:

```
MyGLBox::MyGLBox(QWidget *parent):QGLWidget(parent){
   XRot = YRot = ZRot = 0;
    theta1 = theta2 = phi = 0;
}
```

Comment: likely, what's happening has little to do with `enum`s at all. please post the exact code

Comment: is this for iphone? if so please specify.

Comment: http://ideone.com/dSIMv . No mistakes in the code you have shown. Show the content of other stuff.

Comment: posting the mac osx crash report would help?

Comment: btw I runned the debugger, and it actually work all fine until the addWidget function, could be a Qt bug?

Comment: I see two obvious suspects: 1) forgetting to allocate `GLlayout` properly in `MainProject`; 2) the constructor for `MyGLBox`. Start looking at those.

Comment: I did it with the designer... so I hope is allocated alright, I'll post the constructor, thx for help

Comment: Have you initialized the `enum directions head_dir_ask` to some value?  like `UP` `DOWN` etc.

Comment: in the constructor of `Snake` I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not nearly enough information in your question to point you in any particular direction. However, it's almost certainly because somewhere *else* in your code there is some pointer manipulation that goes wild and ends up accessing something undefined. Changing the memory layout of objects (such as adding or removing an unused member) can temporarily mask such an error -- which is not a good thing because instead if *preventing* the error it is just transforming it from a highly visible and debuggable crash to something subtler and harder to detect, but still an error, whose eventual effects can be much more baffling.

You should run your code in a debugger and inspect what it is doing when you get the exception. (And for your own sake, *don't* change the program in any way that makes the crash go away until you have understood *why* it crashed and are sure you have fixed the underlying cause).

Comment: the debugger stops and return this line:  
ui->GLlayout->addWidget(glwidget);  
I know there is not so much information but I'm really clueless too... :(